# How to use regular expression for letters and numbers with dashes

Tags: regex, unix, search, string-matching

So this is what I have currently in my shell script. I am pretty bad at regular expressions.

```
echo $1 | grep -E '^[A-Z]${3}|^[0-9]${4}|^[ABCD]$'
```

I need my input like this:

```
./dlchek.sh ACV-1319-A
```

This is the general format: **XYX-1111-A** where XYX can be any letter, 1111 can be any number, and A has to be either (A,B,C,D). I am using unix by the way. I only need to check if the format is correct and exit with code 0 if it is correct or 1 if it is incorrect.

This is expected output: Where line 3 is the only one that worked because it followed format.

```
[you@blue final]$ ./dlcheck.sh ACV-13-A
[you@blue final]$ echo $?
1
[you@blue final]$ ./dlcheck.sh ACV-13119-A
[you@blue final]$ echo $?
1
[you@blue final]$ ./dlcheck.sh ACV-1319-A
[you@blue final]$ echo $?
0
[you@blue final]$ ./dlcheck.sh ACV-1319-Y
[you@blue final]$ echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[ABCD]$
```

What are those $$ doing in there?  too many endings. And those pipes??  Do like me, use https://regex101.com/ and you'll learn something every time..

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried it in the regex101 and it worked but did work in my .sh. This is what i have now: grep -E '^[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[ABCD]$'

Comment: is that pattern the entire thing in the file?

Comment: Yes, that is the only thing so far to check. I will add the exit codes and loops after if figure this out. I have it actually set to a variable. so basically like this:     x=`echo $1 | grep -E '^[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[ABCD]$'` echo $x to see if it matches

Comment: I meant is there other content in the file besides what you're looking for. Because if not you need other delimiters than ^ and $.  How about \b? \s?

Comment: How would I implement that to the format described in the description along with the code I have now?

Comment: You'd look at at a file and see what surrounds the pattern wanted.  If it was spaces you could use \s. And you know, you'd look at what you have so far and substitute :-)

Comment: I figured it out actually, I was missing the ( ) around the dashes. It should have been (-)